# How to create a "floated" drop cap (possibly without using float or initial-letter)?

Tags: css, properties, css-float

How to create a "floated" drop cap like this without using `float` or `initial-letter`?

[image]

So far the only solutions I've got from Googling is to use `float` or `initial-letter`, but neither is great. `float` makes it hard to highlight the drop cap for copying because the `::first-letter` is removed from the document flow, while `initial-letter` is experimental and therefore currently unusable.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `:first-letter` to simply hide the first letter so we can still select it then you can consider a pseudo element with data attribute to create the drop card.

Here is example where you can select the whole text and you will also get the `L`:

```css
.drop-card:before {
  content:attr(data-l);
  float:left;
  font-size:1.9em;
  margin-right:5px;
}
.drop-card:first-letter {
   font-size:0;
}
```

```html
<p class="drop-card" data-l="L">
Lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum
</p>
```

Here is another idea where you can wrap your element inside a span that you position over the floated element:

```css
.drop-card:before {
  content:attr(data-l);
  opacity:0;
  float:left;
  font-size:1.9em;
  margin-right:5px;
}

.drop-card {
  position:relative;
}
.drop-card span {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  font-size:1.9em;
}
```

```html
<p class="drop-card" data-l="L">
<span>L</span>orem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum
</p>
```

Comment: This kinda works, but wouldn't it confuse users? Visually, you still can't highlight the drop cap.

Comment: You have failed the readers. The question is "How to create a “floated” drop cap without using float or initial-letter?" - In your first and second example, you used float.

Comment: @JaredNewnam read the question *fully*. The OP asked not to use float because he didn't succeed on making something good with float but I was able to do. Worth to note that the OP accepted my answer.

Comment: @JaredNewnam there is nothing to edit, the question is pretty clear (and the answer too)

Comment: Seriously? I've been searching the web on "how to create a dropcap without float" and this SO question popped right up. The question is useless because the answer doesn't answer the OP's question. I'm glad the OP accepted your answer, but the question is poorly worded, especially since SEO is pointing search engines to it, when it's the opposite of what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Millhorn This one was a long time ago so I don't remember how exactly I phrased it, but I can see you edited it yourself. Apologies for causing you such frustration.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw - Wow! That takes me back a while. Thanks.